# synonym for professional in context

Tags: synonyms

Can somebody give me synonyms for "professional" and "make a living" in the following context:

> Do most professional sportsmen make a good living?

Comment: your given quote seems perfectly acceptable to me, that's how I'd describe it

Comment: yes it is. But i would want to have a synonym because I want to answer this question.

Comment: I suggest you don't use "sb" for "somebody".  It is used in dictionary definitions but not in normal writing.  Do check a thesaurus before posting and explain why you don't think the suggestion are useful. Explain why you want a synonym. And watch for capital letters. And don't ask us to do your homework.

Comment: [A sportsman or an athlete?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93924/can-we-use-the-word-sportsman-to-refer-to-a-person-who-engages-in-sport-activi)

Comment: money-earning athletes. But, in general, professional has no synonym.

Comment: @Lambie: "But, in general, professional has no synonym". What about a tennis pro, 
a pro golfer?

Comment: @VictorB. pro means professional....

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are hoping for a word that means one who does sport for payment. There isn't another word that has exactly the same meaning (except perhaps "pro" which is merely an abbreviation).

You can say:

> Do most top sportsmen earn lots of money.

Since being a professional athlete implies you are at the top, and the question implies you are talking about being paid (for sport).  So this sentence would be understood the same way as yours.

I'm not sure if you intended to only as about *men* (and exclude women)

Comment: "I assume you are hoping for a word that means one who does sport for payment. There isn't another word that has exactly the same meaning." What about a pro athlete?

Comment: Addressed, but that rather like saying "Mr" is a synonym of "Mister"... I don't think that's the sort of thing the OP is looking for.